# I am studying webrtc I want to test the svc and simulcast methods Is there a place to test?

Tags: webrtc

I am studying webrtc
I want to test the svc and simulcast methods
Is there a place to test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Simulcast

Check followings. It give you very nice overview about simulcast.

- https://webrtchacks.com/a-playground-for-simulcast-without-an-sfu/

You can test with just your local web server or even code sandbox, jsbin or jsfiddle.

Just create basic peer connection, and manipulate SDP or PeerConnection APIs.

- https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/pc1/

After that, you can try with PeerConnection's addTransceiver method for this.

- https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#simulcast-example

```
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true});
selfView.srcObject = stream;
pc.addTransceiver(stream.getAudioTracks()[0], {direction: 'sendonly'});
pc.addTransceiver(stream.getVideoTracks()[0], {
  direction: 'sendonly',
  sendEncodings: [
    {rid: 'f'},
    {rid: 'h', scaleResolutionDownBy: 2.0},
    {rid: 'q', scaleResolutionDownBy: 4.0}
  ]
});
```

### SVC

Currently, WebRTC 1.0 does not support SVC. It should be in WebRTC NV(NextVersion).

- https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-svc/
- https://webrtchacks.com/chrome-vp9-svc/

From now, only chrome offer SVC VP9 as a experiment feature with flag.

> chrome --force-fieldtrials=WebRTC-SupportVP9SVC/EnabledByFlag_2SL3TL

You can test with Janus media server.

https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/vp9svctest.html

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has filed an "Intent to Implement" statement on SVC support.  Issue is here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=986069
"Proof of Concept" code is here: 
https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/1710555